# Has the behavior of numpy.in1d changed when passing a set?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting different behavior from `in1d` depending on which machine I run my script on.
On my desktop (numpy version 1.6.2) I try

```
x = np.array('a b c d e f g h i j'.split()) 
np.in1d(x, set(['f', 'e', 'r']))
array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

which is what I expected. On my laptop (version 1.8.1) The result is all `False`, which is not what I want.

Playing around a little, I discovered that

```
np.in1d(x, ['f', 'e', 'r'])
```

works in both versions, but I don't understand why the function doesn't behave as expected when passed a set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do not know when/if a change was made, but this is because the second argument of `np.in1d` has to be an array-like. Sets are not array-likes because they are not ordered.

You can (kind of) see this issue if you try to convert a set to an array. Instead of a 1-d array like you might expect, you get a strange 0-d object.

```
a = np.array(set([1, 3, 5, 6]))

print(repr(a))
# array({1, 3, 5, 6}, dtype=object)

print(a.shape)
# ()
```

You could argue that it should raise an exception or something instead of simply going through with the operation, but that's how the code currently works. It doesn't seem like `np.in1d` (or any similar functions) will be modified, so it's best to get into the habit of converting sets to lists before passing them to numpy functions.

There is an existing [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3892) regarding this on github.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that ticket in my google search. The change must have happened since 1.6, because sets work there. The treatment of lists, tuples, sets and ndarrays is the hardest part of Python to get my head around.

Comment: @Fergal In general, I think it's safe to say that any array-like that you pass into a numpy function should be convertible with `np.array`. So if you try `np.array` on an object and it doesn't give you what you expect, you probably want to convert it to something else. Lists and tuples are usually safe.